# Is there a way to prevent MPJwt authenticating unprotected / permitted endpoints. Using Openliberty server

Tags: open-liberty, microprofile

1. Mpjwt configuration for open liberty server.xml

   ```
   <mpJwt
      id="keycloakJwt"
      jwksUri="https://auth.ura.go.ug/auth/realms/sso/protocol/openid- connect/certs"
      issuer="https://auth.ura.go.ug/auth/realms/sso"
      userNameAttribute="preferred_username"
      audiences="askura-etax-ws">
   </mpJwt>
   ```
2. Unprotected route return the following error when accessed  CWWKS5522E: The MicroProfile JWT feature cannot perform authentication because a MicroProfile JWT cannot be found in the request.

   ```
   @PermitAll
   @Path("/test")
   public class TestResource {
     @Inject
     AppProperty appProperty;

     @GET
     @Path("/ping")
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String test() {
        return "TEST";
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The code around the CWWKS5522E message was recently updated in https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/pull/15606 in 21.0.0.2 to not be issued when the resource is unprotected. Please confirm if you are using at least that release or a newer one. If you are, please open an issue in https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues and we can assist you in debugging your problem.

Regards,

Teddy